# Mongoose query doesn't work with where() when filtering by numeric values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I am having trouble with queries using mongoose when using the where clause.  They work when I filter on strings, but not with numbers.

Here is my model/schema:

```
// Schema
var Wheel = new  mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    method: String,
    size: Number,
    width: Number,
    weight: Number
});


// Model
var WheelModel = mongoose.model('Wheel', Wheel);
```

This query works:

```
var query = WheelModel.find();

query.where('method').equals('Cast/Spun');
query.limit(10);

query.exec(function (err, wheels) {
    // wheel objects are returned
});
```

This is an example of a wheel object inside the array 'wheels'

```
{
"_id": "523de98b263add11a8d4fc4a",
"name": "AME Circlar RS",
"weight": 18.1,
"width": 7,
"method": "Cast/Spun",
"size": 15
}
```

This query below returns [], and does so for if I filter by size, width, and weight, and for any numbers

```
var query = WheelModel.find();

query.where('size').equals(15);
query.limit(10);

query.exec(function (err, wheels) {
    if (!err) {
        return res.send(wheels);
    } else {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I have also tried

```
query.where('size', 15);
query.where('size', '15');
var query = WheelModel.find({ size: 15});
```

If I go:

```
query.where('size').ne(15);
```

Then I get results back, but they will include values where the size is 15.  So I suspect I have some type issues, I just don't know what.  Any help would be apprecicated!

Comment: Can you verify & tell us the type in MongoDB for field `size`?

Comment: They're strings.  I haven't checked but I know this is the problem.  I remember mongoose throwing errors because of the types I defined in the schema, so I just assumed mongoose would throw an error... Bad assumption.

Comment: In the [Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), Check the example and check particularly the `age` field or this particular [example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_number_SchemaNumber-max) on **`Number`** type Field. Hope this ends your search for solution.. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following schema it should work for you (as per understanding from your comments) with the same query i.e. `query.where('size').equals(15)`

```
var Wheel = new  mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    method: String,
    size: { type: Number },
    width: { type: Number},
    weight: { type: Number }
});
```

For more information, check this [Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) in API docs.